# Some invoices not showing on grid and email not sent, but row are created in DB

Tags: magento-1, email, grid, invoice, magento1.9.3

We have been having this occasional issue, for some orders, the payment is processed (by any of our methods), the sales_flat_invoice_* records are created for the invoice, the items and the grid. But we can't see the invoice in the grid for that order, or on the invoices grid and the invoice was not sent to the customer. I can't invoice the order.

We started to see this issue when we added ShipperHQ. But there not seems to be a certain shipping condition that triggers the issue.

I haven't found any pattern except that orders are 2x or 3x our average order total, but other than that, from customers in different groups, different payment methods, different shipping conditions and in no particular frequency.

If the entry for the grid and for the invoice exists, what may be blocking it from showing up? What could I check on the workflow that is blocking this from showing up and email invoice?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Did you find a cause for this? We have the exact same problem and we are missing some invoice numbers in invoice grid. They do appear in the sales_flat_invoice table.

Comment: See also https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Order-Missing-Invoice/m-p/126725/highlight/true#M9468

Comment: Also https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-25/acsd-47910-missing-orders-invoices-shipments-credit-memos-in-respective-entity-grids.html?lang=en, but it’s for Magento 2